# .exe MATLAB file decompilation

Tags: matlab, decompiling, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am trying to decompile a 32KB .exe MATLAB file. I tried the [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/index.php) software, it extracts the project m-files and figures. the figures are ok and the MATLAB can show them. but when I open the m-files, it contains unmeaning characters.

how can I see the m-files codes? Do you know any other suitable software?

thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you already got your answer: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.matlab/sDJlzouFX74/gNPvlqrCOA4J

Answer (score 1):

If the .exe file has been produced with MATLAB Compiler, this is not possible. The MATLAB code is encrypted as part of the deployment process.